# WordPress tax_query based on gender

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress tax_query that is confusing me.

I have posts that relate to products. Each product is in a category relating to gender.

So some posts are in 'mens', some are in 'womens'. But some products are in both 'mens' & 'womens'. For example a backpack. Then some products (like an appliance) isn't in either 'mens' or 'womens'.

So how do I query that using WP_Query? You can see my attempt below, but it doesn't work when a post is in both 'mens' and 'womens'. Any ides?

```
// Build Gender Tax-Query, based on known user gender
if($user_gender == 'male') {
    // User is a male
    $gender_query = array(
      'taxonomy'    => 'category',
      'field'   => 'slug',
      'terms'   => 'womens',
      'operator'    => 'NOT IN'
    );

} elseif($user_gender == 'female') {
    // User is a female
    $gender_query = array(
      'taxonomy'    => 'category',
      'field'   => 'slug',
      'terms'   => 'mens',
      'operator'    => 'NOT IN'
    );          
} else {
    // User is unknown gender
    $gender_query = array();
}

// Get posts
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'    => 2,
    'orderby'           => 'rand',
    'tax_query'         => array(
        'relation'      => 'AND',
        $gender_query
    ),
);
$posts = get_posts($args);
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest building a custom SQL query to pass to `$wpdb`, since complex taxonomy queries are notoriously harder to implement than their SQL equivalents.

**Note**: You can always [output the most recent SQL WordPress executed](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Save_queries_for_analysis). This is a very nice way to debug these kind of problems.

Back to your question, this is what the final code snippet would look like:

```
$gender = 'unknown';

$taxonomy = array('male' => 'mens', 'female' => 'womens');

$where_clause = '';
if ( array_key_exists($gender, $taxonomy) ) {
    $where_clause = sprintf("WHERE %s = '%s'", "$wpdb->terms.slug", $taxonomy[$gender]);
}

$query = "SELECT $wpdb->posts.* FROM $wpdb->posts
INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
INNER JOIN $wpdb->terms ON ($wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = $wpdb->terms.term_id)
$where_clause";

$posts = $wpdb->get_results($query);
```

**Update**:

If you prefer to use tax_query:

```
$gender = 'unknown';

// Build Gender Tax-Query
if($gender == 'male') {
    $gender_query = array(
        'relation'      => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy'    => 'category',
            'field'   => 'slug',
            'terms'   => 'mens',
            'operator'    => 'IN'
        )
    );

} elseif($gender == 'female') {
    $gender_query = array(
        'relation'      => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy'    => 'category',
            'field'   => 'slug',
            'terms'   => 'womens',
            'operator'    => 'IN'
        )
    );
} else {
    $gender_query = array(
        'relation'      => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy'    => 'category',
            'field'   => 'slug',
            'terms'   => array('mens', 'womens'),
            'operator'    => 'IN'
        )
    );
}

// Get posts
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'    => 2,
    'orderby'           => 'rand',
    'tax_query'         => $gender_query 
);
$posts = get_posts($args);
```

The key to both answers is that you should not *exclude* items based on gender, but rather include (assuming the gender neutral items are properly categorized in *womens* and *mens*).

Comment: Hey Niklas, I updated my question a little. The if() statement is actually built around knowing the users gender. So your answer wouldn't work if a user was a male, it wouldn't show an item that was in both womens and mens categories.

Comment: If a post was in "appliances" and not in either 'womens' or 'mens', then the tax_query you gave wouldn't return that post. Would the $wpdb find that post?